# Minimal setup requierements for shadows in three.js

Tags: three.js

Should be enaugh:

```
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

//for object
    model.castShadow = true;
    model.receiveShadow = true;

//for ground
plane.receiveShadow = true;

//for light
    light.castShadow = true;
```

but it's not. What am I missing? Here's my full code:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/245215/2593611/jiHVulw07RlMXSB/rings.7z

Comment: make sure that light is correctly positioned ( is not positioned under the object or so). Use a `DirectionalLightHelper` , which will help you determine light's position and direction.

Comment: Here's a screenshot with DirectionalLightHelper: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52763164/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%C2%A02016-08-25%20o%C2%A012.34.15-fullpage.png) light.intensity is set up to 0.5

Comment: Can you check by changing the angle of the SpotLight? Try with less than 90 degree. Maybe `Math.PI / 3`.

Comment: @Rasheduzzaman_Sourov Yes, it was the reason - I taught light.rotation == light.angle and the reason is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you set the near parameter a little too far. Set it to:

```
 light.shadow.camera.near = 1;
```

and it should be working just fine.

**Update:**

Also noticed that your light angle is incorrect too, I'd suggest changing it to at least `Math.PI / 4` so it's facing the right direction.

Comment: Still I can't see difrence, maybe only at the edges of scene ;( [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52763164/Zrzut%20ekranu%20(18).png) or maybe objects are too small to notice it, or there is too much other light

Comment: try changing the SpotLight distance to 100 and angle to Math.PI / 4 ; like this `light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1, 100, Math.PI / 4, 1);` and `light.position` to `light.position.set(0,10,4);`